# Reading from a file in android studio and testing on phone

Tags: android

I am trying to read from a text file in Android Studio.

```
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("./quizdata.txt");
int size = fin.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
fin.read(buffer);
fin.close();
```

Now, when I run this test on a phone connected to my computer, android doesn't find this file. My best guess is, the file should be on my phone and not on the computer.

If yes, at what location in the phone shall I store this file?

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you just include it in your app package and start reading from it!

Comment: You can place this file in your asset folder and read from there, else you can also store this in phone local storage and then use from there

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the file to your Android code, not to your Android phone. You need to save it either in **assets** folder (src/main/assets) or **raw** folder (src/res/raw).

If you save it in the raw folder, you can read it with:

```
// you don't need to have the file extension. Note that you can't use uppercase
InputStream is = Context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quizdata);
```

If you save it in asset folder, you can read it with:

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("quizdata.txt");
```

To get all the lines in the file, you can use the following code:

```
// getting all the line
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder quiz = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    quiz.append(line).append('\n');
}
```